# how to connect different html pages and put the actions behind buttons on them?

Tags: php, html, web, dreamweaver

i m working on website i have designed 3 html pages now i want to connect these pages by `button click` on them , for example if user select one option from drop down menu and click on it , it will go to the next html page etc.

for example , am trying to show similar example in below image

If one option select `To` field and one from `From` field then click on search , it should move to next page

[image]

My Html Try :

```
</form>     
        <p class="h2">Quick Search</p>
        <div class="sb2_opts">
         <p>
       </p>
 <form method="post" action="flights.html" >
     <p>Enter your source and destination.</p>
    <p>
        From:</p>
   <select name="from">
  <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
  <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
  <option value="murree">Murree</option>
  <option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
    <p>
        To:</p>
       <select name="To">
  <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
  <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
  <option value="murree">Murree</option>
  <option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search" /> 
</form>
    </form> </table>
```

in this code after every different entry in dropdown menu and click on search button will open different html page. Can anyone give me a clue if I do it in PHP then how ? any link or example is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: as i am new to it, i just need a sample run or a clue of any logic,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. You could update the action of the form based upon the select you care about or
2. You could redirect or include from a processing page

The second option is better because it reduces redundant processing code on the different pages, so on the processing page, you check which select option was passed and either include the HTML page you want or redirect to it using the `header("Location:");` function in php.

Based on this, you would set the form action to something like "flights-processing.php".  In flights-processing.php would be:

```
<?php 
 $from =  isset($_POST['from'])?$_POST['from']:'';
 $to = isset($_POST['to'])?$_POST['to']:'';

 if( $from =='Islamabad'){
     if($to == 'Lahore'){
         header('Location: islma-lahore.html');
      }
?>
```

With additional logic for each to/from and also if one or both were not selected.  This is a very simple example and there are better ways to do it, but it would work.

Comment: The second option. Set the action of the form to a handler that then decides what to present to the visitor. The experience created by the `header("Location: ...");` will match your stated expectations.

Comment: what should be added in <form method="post" action="" > ,when i enter any page in action only that page open.it not proceed the other pages below in switch statement

Comment: It should be `action="flights-processing.php"` or whatever page you want to have the logic for which other page should be displayed based on selections made.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="h2">Quick Search</p>
    <div class="sb2_opts">
     <p>
   </p>
<form method="post" action="" >
 <p>Enter your source and destination.</p>
<p>
    From:</p>
<select name="from">
<option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
<option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
<option value="murree">Murree</option>
<option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<p>
    To:</p>
   <select name="To">
<option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
<option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
<option value="murree">Murree</option>
<option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search" /> 
</form>
</form> </table>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['from']) and isset($_POST['To'])) {
$from = $_POST['from'] ;
$to = $_POST['To'] ;
$table = array($from, $to);

switch ($table) {
  case array ("Islamabad", "Lahore") :
  header("Location: page1.html");
 break;
  case array ("Islamabad", "Murree") :
  header("Location: page2.html");
 break;
  case array ("Islamabad", "Muzaffarabad") :
 header("Location: page3.html");
 break;
//.....
//......
default:
echo "Your choice is nor valid !!";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: what should be added in `<form method="post" action="" >` ,when i enter any page in action only that page open.it not proceed the other pages below in `switch` statement